# SQL if then statement

Tags: sql

```
retry:
exec xxxxxxxxx

if @csvfilecount < 16
   begin
      waitfor delay '00:05:00'
      goto retry
   end
else
   begin
      send email
   end
```

I like to use go to retry for 2 try only and then go to send email. 
Not sure to how do this. Please help. Thanks

Comment: There is no if in SQL (the query language). Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: declare a variable.  add 1 to it for each retry.  if the variable is greater than 2 do not retry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use a while loop with a counter?

```
declare @counter as int
set @counter = 0

while @counter <= 2
begin
   @counter = @counter + 1
   -- your code here
   -- update @csvfilecount
   if @csvfilecount < 16
   begin
       waitfor delay '00:05:00'         
   end
   else
   begin
      send email
      -- do you want to BREAK here?
   end
end
```

Comment: so no need add retry here?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but this will loop thru 2 times.  You will need to update csvfilecount before the if statement so the code will know whether to wait or send an email.  You probably also want a break statement in the else portion if you want to stop checking csvfilecount.  

See updates in code above.

Comment: I think missing "set" @counter =@counter + 1